# Parse XML using Simple XML Parser

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML.

```
<report>
<location city="Paris [Paris;France]">
<interesting>...</interesting>
<var>
<name>Minimum temperature</name>
<icon>4</icon>
<data>
<forecast data_sequence="1" value="2"/>
<forecast data_sequence="2" value="2"/>
<forecast data_sequence="3" value="4"/>
<forecast data_sequence="4" value="4"/>
<forecast data_sequence="5" value="3"/>
<forecast data_sequence="6" value="8"/>
<forecast data_sequence="7" value="6"/>
</data>
</var>
<var>
```

I want to retrieve the first instance of "value", and then be able to retrieve further "value's" later on using the same sort of method.

How do I retrieve its value?

This what I have so far, but this gives no output for me.

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("weather.xml");

$a = $xmlDoc->location[0]->city['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $xmlDoc->location[0]->var[0]->data[0]->forecast[2]["value"];
```

Note: this is using the API for TheWeather.com for anyone interested.